# take(eventChannel) taking all the actions instead of the emitted result

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to subscribe to firebase onAuthStateChanged using the eventchannel in redux-saga, I managed to put a sandbox showing the status

https://codesandbox.io/s/42kwzv2324

Line number 71 and 72 in sagas/sagas.js, I am logging the result of **take**, I find that all the actions are being logged instead of the user that is emitted from the event channel.

What am I doing wrong? I am not able to debug as the log inside callback of **onAuthStateChanged** is not hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your sandbox is that you are incorrectly importing eventChannel.

Change:

```
import eventChannel from "redux-saga";
```

To:

```
import {eventChannel} from "redux-saga";
```

In your current code you are creating new saga middleware instead of eventChannel. Saga middleware is a function, which is a supported parameter of `take`. Since the saga middleware function always returns truthy value, the `take` effect is triggering for every dispatched action.